# jQuery Sortable implementation with database

Tags: jquery, database, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I have been trying to work on updating the database with the new order of the sorted list items. I was trying to follow this tutorial but found myself quite lost later into the tutorial, felt I was out of my depth (didn't help he referred to code that had been previously written & is no longer available on their forums). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mOs0VY_sIw

I'm looking to sort a list like the following (one that can be added to or entries can be removed) http://dev.michaelbole.com/cms/

The following shows my front end:

```
<ul id="sortable">
<?php
    $sortget = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM sortable", $connection);

    $sortget = explode(',', $sortget[0]['data']);
    print_r($sortget);


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM bookwrite", $connection);
    if (!$result){
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<li id='item_".$row["id"]."'>"."<h1>".$row["post_title"]."</h1>"."<p>".$row["post_details"]."</p>"."</li>";   
    }   

?>

</ul>
```

JS:

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            containment: 'parent',
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            revert: 'true',
            opacity:'0.60',
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                console.log(postData);  

                $.post('save.php', {list: postData}, function(o) {
                    console.log(o);
                }, 'json');
            }

    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

and save:

```
<?php

$list = $_POST['list'];

$output = array();
$list = parse_str($list, $output);
print_r($output);
$save = implode(',',$output['item']);
require_once("includes/connection.php");

echo $list;
mysql_query("UPDATE sortable SET 'data' = '$save'", $connection);

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).